# How to initialize okHttp's MockServer() in a repository?

Tags: android, okhttp, android-mvvm, mockwebserver

Server.kt (is a mock server that will return a list of Users)
https://github.com/shalbert94/androidinterview/blob/master/server/src/main/java/com/jobrapp/server/Server.kt

For some reason,  `val server = Server()` called in my repository (https://github.com/shalbert94/androidinterview/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/jobrapp/androidinterview/MockServerRepository.kt) throws:
`Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.jobrapp.androidinterview/com.jobrapp.androidinterview.MainActivity}: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException`

The issue seems to stem from calling `MockWebServer()`'s `start()` method which is called in `Server`'s `init` block. How can I initialize `Server` in my repository without triggering a NetworkOnMainThreadException?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you Kotlin coroutines!

```
fun getUsers(liveData: MutableLiveData<List<User>>) = launch {
        val server = async{ Server() }

        server.await().getUsers().enqueue(object: Callback<List<User>> {...})
    }
```